# Time reversal of superconducting order parameter?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity, second-quantization, time-reversal-symmetry

This pedagogical [material](https://boulderschool.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/Introduction-to-Unconventional-Superconductivity.pdf) discusses the transformation of the superconducting order parameter $\Delta_k$ (matrix in spin space). Eq. (79) applies the time-reversal operator $K=-i\sigma^yC$ (complex conjugation operator $C$) to a fermion annihilation operator
$$ Kc_{ks}= -i\sigma^y_{ss'}c^\dagger_{-k,s'}.$$

While the $\sigma^y$ multiplication is fine, how is annihilation changed to creation? This looks inconsistent with the first set of equations in this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/708904/20564) or the similar form in this [review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.2026) (P44 bottom left).
However, without this transform to creation, how to understand the complex conjugate in Eq. (80) $$K\Delta_{k}=\sigma^y\Delta_{-k}^*\sigma^y$$ below Eq. (79)? It looks like $\langle c^\dagger c^\dagger \rangle=\langle cc \rangle^*$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer, but I hope it's at least helpful.

I also can't see how to reconcile the statements

(1) $K c_{ks} = -i\sigma^y_{ss'} c^\dagger_{-k, s'}$ and

(2) $ K \hat{c}_{\uparrow} K^{-1} = \hat{c}_{\downarrow}; K \hat{c}_{\downarrow} K^{-1} = -\hat{c}_{\uparrow}$.

When working with antilinear objects, we first need to establish a phase convention. Suppose you have two bases for the 1D complex vector space formed by the vacuum - $|0\rangle$, and $|0'\rangle = e^{i\phi} |0\rangle$. How does $C$ act on these bases? If you suppose that $C | 0 \rangle = | 0 \rangle$, then you end up with the strange-looking

$$ C | 0' \rangle = e^{-i\phi} |0\rangle = e^{2i\phi} |0'\rangle.$$

where $C$ is complex conjugation. This is often suppressed by picking a phase convention for the vacuum that ensures that $C |0\rangle = |0 \rangle$. Choosing the same convention for all basis kets, defined as $c^\dagger_{s} |0 \rangle$ means that $Cc_{s} C \equiv c_s$.

In short, the action of time reversal can change the phases in front of operators, but does not mix orthogonal states.

However, I believe that (2) is consistent with the claimed superconducting order parameter transformation.

The SC order parameter operator (as a matrix) is written such that

$$ \hat{\Delta}(k) = \begin{pmatrix} \hat{c}_{-k\uparrow} & \hat{c}_{-k\downarrow} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \Delta_{\uparrow\uparrow}(k) & \Delta_{\uparrow\downarrow}(k) \\ \Delta_{\downarrow\uparrow}(k) & \Delta_{\downarrow\downarrow}(k) \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \hat{c}_{k\uparrow} \\ \hat{c}_{k\downarrow} \end{pmatrix}
 = \Delta_{ss'}(k)\hat{c}_{-k s}\hat{c}_{k s'} $$

In second quantisation, symmetries acts on operators by the *conjugation action* (i.e. in the adjoint representation). Due to decades of sloppy notation, we end up with garbage like

$$ \tilde{K} \hat{\Delta}(k)  = K \Delta_{ss'}(k)\hat{c}_{-k s}\hat{c}_{k s'}K^{-1} $$

$$ = -i \sigma^y C \Delta_{ss'}(k)\hat{c}_{-k s}\hat{c}_{k s'} i \sigma^y C 
\hspace{3em} \text{(*)}
$$

Now there is a problem - we defined how $C$ acts on $|\uparrow\rangle$ for a *single* spin, but how does it act in the full Hilbert space, $\text{Span}\{ c^\dagger_{r,s} |0\rangle ,r \in \text{Points in space} \}$ ?

Suppose that we make the choice of phase $C c^\dagger_{r, s}|0\rangle = c^\dagger_{r, s}|0\rangle$. Then complex conjugation acts non-trivially on $k$ space eigenvectors -

$$C c^\dagger_{k,s}|0\rangle = C\sum_{r}e^{-ik\cdot r} c^\dagger _{r, s} |0\rangle$$

$$ = \sum_{r}e^{ik\cdot r} C c^\dagger _{r, s} |0\rangle = \sum_{r}e^{ik\cdot r}  c^\dagger _{r, s} |0\rangle = c^\dagger_{-k,s} |0\rangle$$

Using the anticommutators, this argument shows that in the standard phase convention, $C c_{k,s} C = c_{-k, s}$.

Using this fact gets you what you want.

$$ K\hat{\Delta}(k)K = +\sigma^y \Delta_{ss'}^*(k) \hat{c}_{k, s} \hat{c}_{-k, s'} \sigma^y $$

$$= -\sigma^y \Delta_{ss'}^*(-k) \hat{c}_{-k, s'} \hat{c}_{k, s}\sigma^y $$

which is the claimed result, since $\Delta(k) = -\Delta(-k)^T$.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer! Weirdly, I haven't received any notification from PSE and I saw it just now... This makes good sense and is consistent with what was in mind. Here, the SC order parameter is treated in the same way as a usual second-quantized Hamiltonian, then $C$ affects the c-number part as well and hence we get $\Delta^*$.

Comment: But at the end of my question, I was thinking more about another viewpoint, i.e., $\Delta$ defined from $\langle c c \rangle$ or so. Then it seems unclear how we can get $\Delta^*$ from the usual $K$ effect I linked or your (2) in the beginning because there $K$ does not mix annihilation and creation. Any thoughts?

Comment: Then you have $\langle cc \rangle^* := \langle 0 |  cc 0 \rangle^* =\langle cc0 | 0 \rangle =  \langle 0 | (cc)^\dagger | 0 \rangle $, where $0$ is the fermion vacuum (i.e. not the superconducting vacuum).

Comment: I mean if we have $\Delta\sim\langle cc \rangle$ and apply $K$ to the two $c$ operators, we don't get two $c^\dagger$s. Then it looks that $K$ does not change $\Delta$ to the expected $\Delta^*$.