# Contradicting time reversal of complex order parameter

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity, second-quantization, time-reversal-symmetry

Consider a complex order parameter $\Delta$, e.g., in the superconducting case. It is well known that its time reversal would lead to $\Delta^*$.

On the other hand, we know the definition $\Delta\sim\langle cc \rangle$. If we apply time reversal to the two $c$ operators, they are still $c$ rather than $c^\dagger$ because time reversal does not mix annihilation and creation operators (e.g., the first set of equations in this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/708904)). Then it seems that one cannot obtain the expected $\Delta^*$, which is just $\langle c^\dagger c^\dagger \rangle$.

What is wrong here?